# Find the combination of variables to give a certain result (soccer)

Tags: probability, functions, gambling

I don't know if it's the correct place to ask.

I'm trying to find a particular function $f(x_1, \dots \ ,x_n)$, where $n=10$ that gives me the probability of both teams to score in second half.

The point is that I know the data and the result but i don't know the function. I explain better:

The variables $x_i$ are number of attacks, dangerous attacks, possession, shots on target and shots off target of both teams in the first half (see the image attachment).

DATA EXAMPLE 1
$x_1 = 50$ (attacks team A on 1st half)
$x_2 = 35$ (dangerous attacks of team A)
$x_3= 45 \% $ (possession of team A)
$x_4 =3$ (shots on target team A)
$x_5 = 1$ (shots off target team A)
$x_6 = 43$ (attacks team B on 1st half)
$x_7 = 25$ (dangerous attacks of team B)
$x_8= 55 \% $ (possession of team B)
$x_9 =2$ (shots on target team B)
$x_{10} = 2$ (shots off target team B)

This data gives me (trough some combination of them that I don't know) $f(x_1, \dots \ ,x_{10})=50,1 \%$ probability for team A to score in 2nd half (or $49,9\%$ for team B to score).

I know 3 sets of DATA + the RESULT given by these sets.

Can I find function $f$? Is there any brute-force program that can calculate it?

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQ22w.png)

Comment: Surely, you'll understand that this amount of data is wildly insufficient. I could put, for example
$$
f(x_1, x_2, \ldots x_{10}) = x_1 + 0.1
$$
and it would fulfill the requirements. So in order to properly find such a function, you'll need probably hundreds of times more data (now you have presented essentially one data point).

Comment: @MattiP. yes, when I'll have lot of data, how I find the function?

Comment: I guess there are many, many ways of doing this and it's almost an artform. You'd maybe have to assume some general form for $f$. Important question to ask, is: Is $f$ linearly dependent on all the variables, or are there nonlinear terms? Also, looking at the variables, perhaps you can join or eliminate some variables? Certainly you can immediately see that $x_8 = 1- x_3$, so $x_8$ can be immediately dropped. Then, maybe you can make new variables like $A = x_1/x_6$, if it makes sense ... So these are just some ideas!